# Is Dirt really 'useless'?

Tags: medieval-engineers

<del>Mining</del> Digging for ores gives me lots and lots of sacks of Dirt. But I see no other possible use besides filling terrain elsewhere.

Come on, that is not a useful use! Only a small fraction of all the Dirt I get is needed for filling other places.

Is there any other use for Dirt, or may I keep dropping it to free space in my Inventory and Chests?

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://medievalengineerswiki.com/w/Dirt), Dirt has no use in any crafting or building recipes. It is solely used for terrain construction. You can safely drop it.

Comment: I would say in 9 out of 10 games where one can acquire dirt, its almost always pretty useless :)